# HTML Landing Page Override for Magento Store

Tags: magento-1.7, admin

is there a way to override a Magento store (a store within a magento install, that isnt the primary one)?

I have a html landing page I want to put in place of the store while Im developing it.

Is this possible? What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple rewrite rule in your `.htaccess`

Eg.

```
# replace to suit the domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com 
# change to suit your own IP
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.x\.x 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.htm$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/maintenance.htm [R=307,L]
```

Comment: That works well, thanks :) The .htaccess file reads the # comment after the HTTP_HOST as an argument however, incase anyone else needs to know this.

Comment: So ive used the above, and all seems to be ok, however its almost like the site is just ignoring the above? It loads as normal, regardless of file location.